# How do you install the eGalaxtouch driver in Ubuntu 18.04 32 bit?

Tags: 18.04, touchscreen

How do I install the eGalaxtouch driver in Ubuntu 18.04 32 bit?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to install the driver on your system? If so, what sorts of errors of errors have you seen?

Comment: I do not know how to install it at all.